# Android AudioTrack only plays first 2 seconds back, then stops

Tags: android, audio, buffer, delay

I'm using an extra thread for AudioTrack to play back a wave file I have previously recorded in another activity.

When I start playback, I get the following output in LogCat:

```
09-13 09:13:13.207: WARN/Archive(1066): audioplayThread is running..., state is: READY
09-13 09:13:21.187: WARN/Archive(1066): wave file /mnt/sdcard/myrecording/myrecording_3_12-09-2011_14-14.wav
09-13 09:13:22.582: WARN/Archive(1066): audioPlayer bufferSize 4090
09-13 09:13:22.582: WARN/Archive(1066): audioPlayer wave length 206432
09-13 09:13:22.601: DEBUG/AudioHardware(75): AudioHardware pcm playback is exiting standby.
09-13 09:13:22.601: DEBUG/AudioHardware(75): openPcmOut_l() mPcmOpenCnt: 0
09-13 09:13:22.683: WARN/AudioFlinger(75): write blocked for 82 msecs, 1 delayed writes, thread 0xcb08
09-13 09:13:24.816: WARN/Archive(1066): playbackHeadposition is: 49591
09-13 09:13:24.816: WARN/Archive(1066): audiostate is: 3
09-13 09:13:26.089: WARN/AudioTrack(1066): obtainBuffer() track 0x298b18 disabled, restarting
09-13 09:13:27.214: WARN/AudioTrack(1066): obtainBuffer() track 0x298b18 disabled, restarting
09-13 09:13:28.332: WARN/AudioTrack(1066): obtainBuffer() track 0x298b18 disabled, restarting
09-13 09:13:29.457: WARN/AudioTrack(1066): obtainBuffer() track 0x298b18 disabled, restarting

...
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: This needs more information. What mode is your AudioTrack set to play back in, STREAM or STATIC? If it's in STREAM, do you have a thread that's writing more data in? How big is the sound data overall?

Answer (score 3):

I just saw the logcat: obtainBuffer() track 0x298b18 disabled, restarting .. 
 that is to say : you have not got audio data and the input audio stream have been stopped .so the buffer must wait for the audio stream in.  i think you should check the inputstream  and the read method. you must ensure that you have read the audio data continuously.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I finally chose not to use AudioTrack after experimenting a lot with different parameters and reading almost every audio thread on stackoverflow. Earlier AudioTrack code worked and then it didn't. It left me with the feeling that the AudioTrack class isn't that reliable. Finally I went with MediaPlayer for audio playback. Maybe it has a bit more overhead, but it's reliable.

Comment: I wouldn't say its unreliable, but you do have to take more care with AudioTrack.

Comment: AudioTrack is not for the faint of heart.  It is very easy to fudge byte feeding into it, resulting in the error you are experiencing.  I haven't figured out the solution to this problem yet either.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem before. I used vitamio bundle which is a counterpart of Android's Media Player and has more audio support. Try adding this code to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I have observed the same issue when number of written samples is not divisible by number of channels.

For example:

number of channels: 2

mAudioTrack.write(buffer, 0, 75);